# Problema com select php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com um problema que nunca vi em php, vou tentar passar um exemplo para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.

Possuo uma tabela `arquivos` nessa tabela possuo 2 colunas sendo elas o `id do arquivo` e o `id do usuário` (a quem este arquivo pertence).

O usuário de `id` **8** esta conectado e no sistema vai listar todos os arquivos que tem o `idUsuario` **8** que são **4 arquivos relacionado ao mesmo** só que meu método de listar arquivos sempre omiti um arquivo exemplo são 4 arquivos registrados com o `idUsuario` **8** ele não me lista 4 arquivos ele esta me listando 3 ou seja um arquivo ele não me mostra, se eu adicionar mais um arquivo pro usuário de `id` **8** ficando com 5 arquivos relacionado ao usuario 8, ele vai me listar 4 em vez de listar os 5.

pelo que entendi interpretando a saída ele ta pegando a quantidade de dados que determinado usuário tem e omitindo sempre o arquivo de menor id da tabela

método listarArquivos

```
public function listarArquivo(){
    try{
        $id_usuario = $this->id;

        $query = new DbFunctions();
        $query->selectFiles("SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE idUsuario = '$id_usuario'");

        //var_dump($id_usuario);
        foreach($query->getResult() as $chave => $dado){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$dado->id_arquivo."</td>
            <td>".$dado->nome."</td>
            <td>".$dado->tamanho."</td>
            <td>".$dado->data."</td>
            <td>
                <a href='visualizar_arquivo.php?acao=visualizar&id_arquivo=".$dado->id_arquivo."'target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-external-link fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                <a href='visualizar_arquivo.php?acao=download&id_arquivo=".$dado->id_arquivo."'target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-cloud-download fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                <a href='?link1=".$dado->id_arquivo."' name='link1' ><i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
            </td>";
        }
        //$query->getResult();
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($query->getResult());
        echo "</pre>";

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Método selectFiles:

```
public function selectFiles($sql){
    $query = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    foreach($query as $row){
        $this->setResult($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
        //$this->setResult($row);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Não sei se esse problema pode ser porque estou pegando o resultado da query e to colocando em um objeto, esse objeto teria um tamanho de armazenamento?

Pode estar um pouco confuso esse meu problema mas também não estou entendendo o motivo desse problema se alguém puder me dar uma ajuda agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente a primeira linha do resultado esteja sendo omitida por causa do `foreach($query as $row)`, que movimenta o cursor uma posição adiante no ResultSet ($query), fazendo com o `fetchAll` pule o primeiro registro, pois já foi processado pelo `foreach`. Uma possivel solução é trocar o `foreach` por um `if`, algo como:

```
public function selectFiles($sql){
    $query = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    //verifica se foram retornados registros pela consulta
    if($query->rowCount()){
       $this->setResult($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
       return true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Obrigado deu certo aqui.

Answer (score -1):

O método listar arquivos não possui o fechamento da `tr`.

> Exemplo correto

```
public function listarArquivo(){
    try{
        $id_usuario = $this->id;

        $query = new DbFunctions();
        $query->selectFiles("SELECT * FROM arquivos WHERE idUsuario = '$id_usuario'");

        //var_dump($id_usuario);
        foreach($query->getResult() as $chave => $dado){
            echo "<tr>
            <td>".$dado->id_arquivo."</td>
            <td>".$dado->nome."</td>
            <td>".$dado->tamanho."</td>
            <td>".$dado->data."</td>
            <td>
                <a href='visualizar_arquivo.php?acao=visualizar&id_arquivo=".$dado->id_arquivo."'target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-external-link fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                <a href='visualizar_arquivo.php?acao=download&id_arquivo=".$dado->id_arquivo."'target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-cloud-download fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
                <a href='?link1=".$dado->id_arquivo."' name='link1' ><i class='fa fa-trash fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>"; // <------ </tr> que faltava 
        }
        //$query->getResult();
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($query->getResult());
        echo "</pre>";

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: o fechamento do TR não ia fazer diferença mesmo porque estava dando um var_dump pra verificar, mesmo fechando o TR ele continua omitindo o primeiro dado que esta no banco de dados

Comment: Perdão José não me atentei a isso. Você pode postar a implementação do método getResult e do método selectFiles?

Answer (score -1):

implementação dos métodos selectFiles, getResult e setResult

método selectFiles

```
public function selectFiles($sql){
    $query = $this->conecta()->query($sql);
    foreach($query as $row){
       $this->setResult($query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ));
       return true;
    }
 }
```

método getResult

```
public function getResult(){return $this->result;}
```

método setResult

```
private function setResult($r){$this->result = $r;}
```

Comment: Isto é uma resposta à sua pergunta original ? Ou seriam mais informações que queria adicionar à pergunta ?